# How to Override props in react native library

Tags: react-native

I wonder how I can override the default props in react native library.
The following is the library:

Thus, if I want to call the library, I simply use

```
import qrcode from 'qrcodescanner'



<qrcode showMarker = {true} /> // change the showMarker props from false to true
```

I want to change the default value from false to true, does anyone have the solution?

```
export default class QRCodeScanner extends Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    onRead: () => console.log('QR code scanned!'),
    reactivate: false,
    vibrate: true,
    reactivateTimeout: 0,
    fadeIn: true,
    showMarker: false,
    cameraType: 'back',
    permissionDialogTitle: 'Info',
    permissionDialogMessage: 'Need camera permission',
    checkAndroid6Permissions: false,
    cameraProps: {},
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scanning: false,
      fadeInOpacity: new Animated.Value(0),
      isAuthorized: false,
      isAuthorizationChecked: false,
      disableVibrationByUser: false,
    };

    this._handleBarCodeRead = this._handleBarCodeRead.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.mainContainer, this.props.containerStyle]}>
        <View style={[styles.infoView, this.props.topViewStyle]}>
          {this._renderTopContent()}
        </View>
        {this._renderCamera()}
        <View style={[styles.infoView, this.props.bottomViewStyle]}>
          {this._renderBottomContent()}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to fork the library and change the default prop as below:

```
export default class QRCodeScanner extends Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    onRead: () => console.log('QR code scanned!'),
    reactivate: false,
    vibrate: true,
    reactivateTimeout: 0,
    fadeIn: true,

    // update this default prop to true
    showMarker: true,

    cameraType: 'back',
    permissionDialogTitle: 'Info',
    permissionDialogMessage: 'Need camera permission',
    checkAndroid6Permissions: false,
    cameraProps: {},
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scanning: false,
      fadeInOpacity: new Animated.Value(0),
      isAuthorized: false,
      isAuthorizationChecked: false,
      disableVibrationByUser: false,
    };

    this._handleBarCodeRead = this._handleBarCodeRead.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.mainContainer, this.props.containerStyle]}>
        <View style={[styles.infoView, this.props.topViewStyle]}>
          {this._renderTopContent()}
        </View>
        {this._renderCamera()}
        <View style={[styles.infoView, this.props.bottomViewStyle]}>
          {this._renderBottomContent()}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change the props inside the library. Instead, I want to change it in my code. Do you have a solution?

Comment: You can override it in your code exactly like you did in the original post.  If you don't want to do this each time you use the component, you can create a component of your own that just overrides this prop and use your own component instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is not good idea, and not suggested,

but if this is the last thing you can do then

go to node_modules find your library and change it locally.

Note:

- not a good idea at first
- only for workaround
- will be available for you and for only this project
- if installed library again it will be removed